# why $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} c \\ d\end{pmatrix}$ have two straight lines?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image]

Im  not getting the meaning  of $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$ and  $\begin{pmatrix} c \\ d\end{pmatrix}$

Suppose if i take $a=1$ , $b=2$   and $c=2 , d=-1$  then $(a,b)=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}=(1,2)$ and similarly  $(c,d)=(2,-1)$

Now if we contruct these points in the  xy-plane , then we will get only  one  straight line .See the diagram given below.

[image]

Here, im confused  that why $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$ and  $\begin{pmatrix} c \\ d\end{pmatrix}$ have  two straight  lines

Comment: These are intended to be vectors pointing from the origin to your given point, not just points in the plane.

Comment: Usually $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$ is used to represent a **vector** with starting point at $(0,0)$ and terminal point at $(a,b)$.

Comment: This is a notation I haven't seen. The usual vector notation I'm familiar with is $\langle a,b\rangle$ or just $a\cap i+b\cap j$ or $(a,b)$ if the context is understood.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas this is just your latter notation in column vector form.

Comment: @boojum Your comment is a bit misleading at best.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Ah true, I think if the author had defined vectors with that column-vector notation to start with, OP shouldn't have been confused.

Comment: Yeah. It's a common point of confusion because the notations for ordered pairs and column/row vectors are so very similar. (For good reason, but still can be confusing.)

Comment: I cannot edit my first comment now, but I meant $a\hat i+b\hat j$. Dumb me used `\cap` instead of `\hat` and didn't check the comment earlier.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$ is meant to be a vector. Typically, in non-mathematical terms, $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$ is the arrow that starts at $(0,0)$ and points towards $(a,b)$. But, that's not all. These vectors are free to be translated. So, $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$ may also be the vector that starts at $(1,1)$ and points towards $\begin{pmatrix} a+1 \\ b+1\end{pmatrix}$ (I leave it to you to draw a picture to understand this translation better). As you might have understood by now, the translation of this vector is just a shift of origin which justifies why vectors don't change under translation.

The line that you have drawn represents $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} c \\ d\end{pmatrix}$ or, in your case $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$ which is $\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$ subject to the assumption that the vector starts at $(2,-1)$ and points towards $(1,2)$. Try to think what hapens to the arrow you've drawn if you translate it such that the tail sits on the origin. Where does the point of the arrow land?

Is the intuition clear now?

I made myself a little too elaborate because I remember my difficulties in understanding vectors when I was studying them for the first time. Hope the answer helps you.

Edit: since you seem to be new to vectors, [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab) can help beginners more than any book can. I can't emphasize its importance enough.